# Get the list of imported ontologies-- OWL API

Tags: java, protege, owl-api

I am using OWL API in order to get information from ontologies. I need to retrieve the list of all imported ontologies used in the loaded ontology.

Is there a method in OWL API can do this task?

my code that load an ontology is:

```
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAnnotationProperty;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataProperty;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLImportsDeclaration;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectProperty;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;

public class NSExtractor {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, OWLOntologyCreationException {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")       
    File testFile= new File("C:\\acco.n3");

    OWLOntologyManager m = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    OWLDataFactory f = OWLManager.getOWLDataFactory();
    OWLOntology o; 
    o = m.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(testFile);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`o.importsDeclarations()` will give you a stream of imports declarations for this ontology. This is the list of IRIs declared with `owl:imports` properties.

Note: these are the declared imports, not the imports closure - the difference is that the imports closure includes the ontologies imported in your ontology and the ontologies imported by these ontologies - recursively including the imported ontologies.

`o.importsClosure()` will provide all ontologies that were loaded during parsing of your ontology.

Comment: As I understand I can use`o.importsDeclarations()`  when ontology have been loaded. But in my case there are some non-direct links to importing ontologies.  
I want to process such links and download ontologies files to local directory to use a set of SimpleIriMappers.

So how is it possible to get IRIs from imports declaration without loading of ontology?
Or is there other way (using of MissingImportListener etc.) to load ontology with non-direct (or even broken) import links?

Comment: ... so it seems that I have to implement custom `OWLOntologyIRIMapper`.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of searches, I found how to solve this task. I used *OWLOntologyXMLNamespaceManager* (I am using OWL API 5.1.6).
Afterward, using getPrefixes and getNameSpaces you can extract prefix and namespaces, respectively, for the loaded ontology as follow:

```
OWLDocumentFormat format = m.getOntologyFormat(ontology);

OWLOntologyXMLNamespaceManager nsManager = new OWLOntologyXMLNamespaceManager(ontology, format);

        for (String prefix : nsManager.getPrefixes()) {
            System.out.println(prefix);
        }
        for (String ns : nsManager.getNamespaces()) {
            System.out.println(ns);
        }
```

Comment: Prefixes and namespaces are not the same thing as imported ontologies.